# broadcasting a comparison of a column of 2d array with multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

What's the right numpy syntax to compare one column against others in a 2d ndarray?

After reading [some](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) [docs](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) on array broadcasting, I am still not quite sure what the correct way to do this is.

**Example:**  Suppose I have a 2d array of goals scored by each player (row) in each game (column).

```
# goals = number of goals scored by ith player in jth game (NaN if player did not play)
                           # column = game
goals = np.array([ [np.nan, 0,      1],   # row = player
                   [     1, 2,      0],
                   [     0, 0, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 1,      1],
                   [     0, 0,      1] ])
```

I want to know if, in the final game, the player achieved a personal record by scoring more goals than she did in any previous game, ignoring games in which she did not appear (represented as `nan`).  I expect `True` for only the first and last players in the array.

Just writing `goals[:,2] > goals[:,:2]` returns the `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (5,2)`

**What I tried:** I know that I can manually stretch the `(5,)` into `(5,2)` with `np.newaxis`.  So this works:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
  personalBest= ( np.isnan(goals[:,:2]) | 
                  (goals[:,2][:,np.newaxis] > goals[:,:2] ) 
                 ).all(axis=1)

print(personalBest) # returns desired solution
```

Is there a less hacky, more idiomatically numpy way to write this?

Comment: This is not hacky.  `np.newaxis` is provided exactly for purposes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
np.flatnonzero((goals[:,None,-1] > goals[:,:-1]).any(1))
```

Let's go through it in steps.

**Step #1:** We are introducing a new axis on the last-column sliced version to keep it as `2D` with the last axis being a singleton dimension/axis. The idea is to compare each of its element against all elements in that row except the element itself :

```
In [3]: goals[:,None,-1]
Out[3]: 
array([[  1.],
       [  0.],
       [ nan],
       [  1.],
       [  1.]])

In [4]: goals[:,None,-1].shape # Check the shapes for broadcasting alignment
Out[4]: (5, 1)

In [5]: goals.shape
Out[5]: (5, 3)
```

**Step #2:** Next up, we are actually performing the comparison against all the columns of the array skipping the last column itself as that's part of the sliced version obtained earlier -

```
In [7]: goals[:,None,-1] > goals[:,:-1]
Out[7]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

**Step #3:** Then, we are checking if there's ANY match along each row -

```
In [8]: (goals[:,None,-1] > goals[:,:-1]).any(axis=1)
Out[8]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

**Step #4:** Finally, getting the matching indices with `np.flatnonzero` -

```
In [9]: np.flatnonzero((goals[:,None,-1] > goals[:,:-1]).any(axis=1))
Out[9]: array([0, 4])
```

Comment: Great explanation - this answer pointed me to the [reference on array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in which i read: `*numpy.newaxis:* The newaxis object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. :const: newaxis is an alias for ‘None’, and ‘None’ can be used in place of this with the same result.`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Excatly! So, with that theory, we could have done `goals[:,-1,None]` too, but with the slicing the last axis is gone, so in effect it becomes the same as `goals[:,None,-1]`, either way leaving us with a last axis as singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Just focusing on the `newaxis` bit:

```
In [332]: goals = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [333]: goals[:,2]>goals[:,:2]
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,2)
```

So the goal is to make the 1st array of shape (3,1) so it can be broadcast against the (3,2):

We can index with a list or slice:  `goals[:,2:3]` works as well

```
In [334]: goals[:,[2]]>goals[:,:2]
Out[334]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

we can explicitly add the `newaxis` (common)

```
In [335]: goals[:,2][:,None]>goals[:,:2]
Out[335]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

we can combine the two indexing operations (this isn't seen as frequently)

```
In [336]: goals[:,2,None]>goals[:,:2]
Out[336]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

we can explicitly reshape:

```
In [339]: goals[:,2].reshape(-1,1)>goals[:,:2]
Out[339]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I don't think the execution times differ significantly.  These are all good `numpy` code.

========

If the 2 arrays were (3,) and (2,3), we wouldn't need any of this.  The numpy broadcasting automatically expands the first to (1,3).  In effect `x[None,:]` is automatic, but `x[:,None]` is not.